# how access web server behind nat using p2p connection

Tags: python-3.x, linux, sockets, networking

I have a web server behind NAT
I'm going to have access
from Internet
My web server
What should I do using peer to peer connection?

Comment: Your question is about Linux, but it is not an entirely programming question. Such questions are off-topic here, but they are on-topic on the https://unix.stackexchange.com . Please visit that site and re-ask there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the thing.
if you wanna connect to a webserver behind nat, there are so many ways, for example check this website:
https://bford.info/pub/net/p2pnat/#rosenberg03traversal
There is a way that named Hole punching that you can punch through nat, search about that and you will find your way.

Comment: i heard about hole punching but idont know how to use it for my web server

Comment: @mehranmaroofi no problem Mehran.

Comment: You can use socket with python and there are some written program on github like:
https://github.com/dwoz/python-nat-hole-punching/
it will help you out.